# What is "us/step" in model.fit() in Tensorflow 2.X

Tags: tensorflow

In one of my runs, I got the time of the run given as "857us/step".[image: 4/4 [==============================] - 0s 857us/step - loss: 0.1914 - mean_squared_error: 0.1914]

I don't know what unit of time it is? Is it smaller than "ms/step"?

Answer (score 0):

Here, the `u` is picked as the closest letter to the lowercase Greek letter "mu", which stands for "micro" as in [microsecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond).

One microsecond is 1000 times **smaller** than 1 millisecond.